# JSF tag not rendered by FacesServlet

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have following web.xml. my jsf tags are rendered fine outsite folder /Pages but not inside it. Is there any problem with the configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/GISPages/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Gis_WebApp</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/SN</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/fages/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>registereduser</role-name>
            <role-name>invitedguest</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Live</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/noauth.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>registereduser</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>invitedguest</role-name>
    </security-role>      
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually the mapping for the faces servlet is based on a file extension:

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

or

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

your mapping only applies to the faces subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

Please give whole predefined path for your welcome file inside 
welcome-file-list  tag. Like as i mention

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/company/dashboard.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```